# Jquery selection gone wrong?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following selection :

```
var squad_name= $("#squad option:selected").text();
```

and the HTML behind looks like this:

```
<div id="squad">
    <label>Squad Type:</label>
    <select id="choosesquad">
        <option value ="0">Choose squad</option>
    </select>
    <input id="setsquad" type="button" value="Set"/><br>

    <div id="unitdiv">
    <label>Choose Unit:</label>
    <select id="chooseunit" class="unit">
        <option value ="0">Choose unit</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Number of units:</label>
    <select id="number" class="unit">
        <option value="0">0</option>      
    </select><br>
</div>
```

for some reason after this selection the squad_name=Choseen Squad Choose unit 0

I just can't figure out: what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? That looks right to me (other than what looks like it must be a typo; surely it's "Choose squareChoose unit0" or something?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're selecting all `<option>` tags in `#squad`, which has 3 `<select>` tags with 3 `:selected` `<option>` tags

`$("#squad option:selected")` is aggregating each selected option from `#choosesquad`, `#chooseunit`, and `#number`

from the sounds of it you need to use this:

```
var squad_name = $("#choosesquad option:selected").text();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Apparently I was temporarily blind.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .val() not .text() to get the value of the option.  You're also selecting all options that are selected, which will fetch an array of 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because `$("#squad option:selected")` returns all  elements and so when you call .text() on that selection, it returns all the text inside each of those elements.

The code below will get the values separately

```
var choosesquad = $("#choosesquad").val();
var chooseunit= $("#chooseunit").val();
var num = $("#number").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all `option`-tags which are currently selected, which will be one from each select, the `text()` function collects the inner text from all selected nodes, resulting in the three text-nodes "Choseen Squad Choose unit 0".